# MATLAB: How do I divide a vector into intervals?

Tags: vectors, algorithms, matlab, programming

I am new to MATLAB and programming in general. I'm afraid I am a bit lost at the moment.

I have been trying to write a MATLAB function that does the following:

Takes inputs "upper" and "number" which are both positive integers. The program should take the interval [$0,$"upper"] and cut it into "number" subintervals which have integer endpoints and are the same length, except for the last interval (if the interval isn't cleanly divisible by number, then the last interval can contain less integer entries).

Then the program should make a vector $x$ with entries that are the beginnings/ends of those subintervals.

---

For example, if I have upper $= 11$ and number $= 3,$ then the program should take the vector

R = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11]

and generate

x = [0 4 8 11].

It should first create subinterval vectors

r1 = [0 1 2 3 4]

r2 = [4 5 6 7 8]

r3 = [8 9 10 11]

and then loop through $x$ and assign $0$ to the first entry and the endpoints of the r's to the other entries of $x$ but I am at a loss as to how to tell MATLAB to do this.

My other problem is that I don't know how to tell MATLAB how to figure out if the interval [$0,$ "upper"] is cleanly divisible by "number" and if not, how to then do to make the last subinterval shorter than the others.

I've sat at this for several days, but I'm not getting anywhere.

Any ideas or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Start with
R = 0:upper;

r = zeros(number,floor(number/upper));
gives you a matrix where each row is the right size for all but your last chunk.

r(:,1) = R(1:number);

Then:
for i = 2:floor(number/upper)
r(:,i) = R((i-1)*number+1:i*number)
end

Something like that. I'm not a super efficient programmer. Then the rows are your output vectors and their endpoints can be used to make the vector x.

Comment: You can use rem(a,b) to see what the remainder of a is when divided by b. then you can check if it's 0 and go from there. But i think it's easier to just deal with it regardless of its length.

Comment: @jbenoit I appreciate you trying to help. Unfortunately, this approach doesn't seem to work when I run it on upper = 11 and number = 3. I think because the upper bound of the for-loop (floor(3/11) ) ends up being zero.

Comment: That's me mixing things up. I switched upper and number in my above comment.

Comment: @jbenoit Thanks, but when I correct for the error and follow through with that, I get $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 3 & 0 \\ 1 & 4 & 0 \\ 2 & 5 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. I don't think that's quite what you meant?